# How do i make my php variable accessible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement a  timer. I learned this idea from a SO post.

```
<?php

  if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && !empty($_POST['username']))
  {
    //secondsDiff is declared here
    $remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
  }
?>
```

This is  my php code. My php,html and JS codes are in the same page. I have a button in my html. When a user clicks on the html page,  It will call a Ajax function

```
                        //url:"onlinetest.php",
                        //dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function()
                        {
                            $(".startMyTest").off('click');
                            setCountDown();
                        }
```

It will call setCountDown() method, which contains a line at the very beginning

```
     var days = <?php echo $remainingDay; ?>;
```

When i run the page,  it says[even before clicking the button] `"expected expression, got '<'"` in the above line. My doubt is

Why this php variable get replaced before i am triggering the button. Please let me know hoe to solve this or how to change my idea.

Comment: Looks like you need to rename your file to `something.php`

Comment: Yes, My file name is testOnlineTest.php

Comment: if your `var days = ...`  line is in an external javascript file, this will not work as it doesn't run through the php parser.

Comment: php runs on the _server_, and _then_ the resulting html and javascript are sent to the client browser.  The browser then renders the html and runs the javascript; the php is already done, effectively _gone_, no longer "in the page" by the time the browser is handling the page.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have mentioned that all scripts are in the same file

Comment: Then what does that actual line look like when its rendered to the page?

Comment: An Notice that i mentioned is getting replaced in that field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, since initial load, `$_POST` values aren't populated (empty on first load),

That variable you set is undefined, just make sure you initialize that variable fist.

```
<?php
// initialize
$remainingDay = 1;
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && !empty($_POST['username']))
{
    //secondsDiff is declared here
    $remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
    echo json_encode(array('remaining_day' => $remainingDay);
    exit;
}
?>

<script>
var days = <?php echo $remainingDay; ?>;
$('.your_button').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'something.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // whatever processes you need
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.remaining_day);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

That is just the basic idea, I just added other codes for that particular example, just add/change the rest of your logic thats needed on your side.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Let me check this.

Comment: @GopsAB just use `document.URL` or hardcode the url if you want.

Comment: @GopsAB although i'd suggest don't go this route, your codes are going to be cluttered, just separate the PHP page that actually handles the request you sent from JS, from the response do what you have to do.

Comment: @GopsAB since there's no context to go on in a larger scale what does this `var days = ` is needed for, why not initialize it in JS instead? do you really need that value coming from the PHP, are your codes (or almost all) always use this way? (echoing php values inside your JS script and stuff)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77860/discussion-between-gops-ab-and-ghost).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var days = "<?php echo $remainingDay; ?>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `php` variable into `JS` code like

```
var jsvariable ="<?php echo $phpvariable ?>";
```

**NOTE:**

If you ever wanted to pass a php's `json_encoded` value to `JS`, you can do

```
var jsonVariable = <?php echo $json_encoded_value ?>; //Note that there is no need for quotes here
```